# How to create combination without the tf-idf?

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I'm trying different combinations of parameters to determine actually which combination of parameters give me the best result. Based on my code shown below, I tried 8 different combination  already but I want to try other combination which is without the tf-idf.

So my question is what should I do to the `parameters` in order to let the python know that after the 8 combinations, now we continue to proceed for without tf-idf (`tf__use_idf`) so that we can have another extra 4 combination (just based on `binary` and `stop_word`) i.e., total 12 combination.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='l2', max_iter=20, verbose=1)),
    ])

    parameters = {
    'vect__stop_words': ('english', None),
    'vect__binary': (True, False),
    'tf__use_idf': (True, False),
    }

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    grid_search.fit(train.x, train.y)
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
pipe = Pipeline([
    # the reduce_dim stage is populated by the param_grid
    ('reduce_dim', 'passthrough'),
    ('classify', LinearSVC(dual=False, max_iter=10000))
])
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'reduce_dim': [SelectKBest(chi2)],
        'reduce_dim__k': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]
```

I got this example from [the documentation.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html)